# Upload large dataset file in database

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, sockets, mongoose

**Feature:**

We're developing a feature that allows administrators to **upload CSV files** in **database** containing up to **1-1.5 million records**. Each subsequent upload is expected to **replace** the existing 1-1.5 million records from database with a fresh set of **2-2.5 million** records or increasing number records.

Furthermore, administrators have **another application** that frequently **accesses** these 2-2.5 million records. With an expected **traffic** of **10,000 to 20,000 live users** on the **site**, **read** operations on **database** are likely to be frequent and intensive.

Given this scenario, we need to carefully plan the implementation of this feature to ensure efficient data management, optimal performance, and seamless user experience. Any guidance and suggestions on how to proceed with this implementation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: You could upload the new records into a new temporary collection, then rename the new collection to the "live" name afterwards.

Comment: @AKX uploading data to temp collection will also cause most write operation and will consume memory, so how we can this process faster?

Comment: If you want the data into the database, of course it will cause write operations and consume memory. You can process it faster with better hardware.

Comment: TBH, MongoDB sounds like a bad choice for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Few advices:

1. Deploy sharded cluster. ( You may need to do some initial testing on how many members , how much RAM and CPU per member etc. )
2. Pre-split the collection so you upload your csv in a distributed way using all available shards.( The tricky part is what to choose as shard key , but since you havent provided any document/schema example and expected use cases it is difficult to say )
3. Use separate new collection for every CSV that you load so you dont affect the previously loaded data query performance.

Comment: I have implemented a similar kind of operation with replicaset. considering a primary and secondary collection, and next time data gets uploaded to secondary, secondary will become primary. Is this approach going to work considering the increasing amount of data?

Comment: if you have enought big servers sure will not be an issue ... , not sure how you upload data to secondary only ( technically speaking secondary is readOnly )